# Unity 3d Saving high score bug

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, save

I have created a simple game where the player collects points on each level, and once the level is completed it will show the total high score. I have recently learned how to save using player prefs and I am able to store the high score of the player in each specific level.

this is the pic when the player completes a level:

[image]

And this is the code for it:

```
 void Update()
{

    int tScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name, 0);//it is adding the points with the highscore again for some reason 
    scoreDisplay.text = "TOTAL POINTS: "+ PlayerController.count.ToString();//display score 
    timeDisplay.text = "TIME LEFT: " + FindObjectOfType<TimeController>().timeText.text;//display remainder time 
    scorePoints = PlayerController.count;
    if (FindObjectOfType<TimeController>().minutes != 0)
    {
        timePoints = (FindObjectOfType<TimeController>().sec + 60)/2;
    }
    else
    {
        timePoints = FindObjectOfType<TimeController>().sec/2;
    }
    highScore = timePoints * scorePoints;
    highScores.text = "HIGH SCORE: " + highScore;

    if (tScore <= highScore)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name, highScore);
    }

}
```

I am saving the entire scene so that the high score for the specific level is saved. The first thing I do is to get the previous high score that the player has scored previously from that same level using the 'GetInt' as tScore or if there is none the default is zero. The high score is then calculated simply by taking the scorePoints (which I get from another class 'PlayerController.count' in the code) and multiply it with the remainder of the time which you can see in the code above. I then compare the highScore with the previous highscore of the same level (tScore) and if it is higher it will override as the new highScore for that level.

This code works most of the time but for some reason, sometimes, the highScore for that scene which is already calculated, adds again with the points (example with the pic above, the high score is 368, but when I use the GetInt, it adds again with the points meaning (368+16 = 384) becoming the high score (overwriting the previous high score) which is wrong. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: Update() is called in every frame (doing the same thing over and over). You only want to do this when the Scene is loaded so move it to Start().

Comment: I cannot do it, if I do , it does not calculate at all, if just shows everything as zero (meaning the total points : 0, time left: 00:00, high score: 0)

Comment: Is this "level-completed script" on a GameObject together with the "game" so to say, or is this script loaded in a scene by itself? I guess it is together with the game, and then we have to make sure it is not called/started before the game has completed. You could for example call this script from the main game loop once it has finished.

Comment: the script is in the canvas, where the player has to collide with an endtrigger which would call upon the gamecontrol which would then call upon this script, activating the panel

Comment: I agree with the @AndersBjerin, you should probably figur out the way to fire the code once, after lvl complete. But aside form that, this line might be wrong `highScores.text = "HIGH SCORE: " + highScore;` since `highScore` can be lower than `tScore`, and in that case I guess you want to print `tScore` because it contains higher value.

Comment: I am also a bit confused on how you calculate the "timePoints". Maybe I misunderstand, but shouldn't it be something like timePoints = (FindObjectOfType<TimeController>().sec + 60 * FindObjectOfType<TimeController>().minutes)/2;    I would of course also store the reference to the TimeController before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I will try to give an answer. Please note that I may have misunderstood what you wanted. Anyway, I would create a simple MonoBehaviour called for example "ShowScore.cs" that can be placed anywhere in the scene (so why not on the canvas).

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ShowScore : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UI.Text scoreDisplay;
    public UI.Text timeDisplay;
    public UI.Text highScores;
  
    public void GameOver()
    {
        string sceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
        int currentHighScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(sceneName, 0);
        TimeController timeController = FindObjectOfType<TimeController>();
    
        int scorePoints = PlayerController.count;
        int seconds = timeController.sec + timeController.minutes * 60;
        Debug.Log("timeController.sec: " + timeController.sec.ToString());
        Debug.Log("timeController.timeText.text: " + timeController.timeText.text);
        int timePoints = (int)(seconds/2f);
        int score = timePoints * scorePoints;

        scoreDisplay.text = "TOTAL POINTS: "+ scorePoints.ToString();
        timeDisplay.text = "TIME LEFT: " + seconds.ToString(); 
    
        if (score > currentHighScore)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt(sceneName, score);
            highScores.text = "HIGH SCORE: " + score.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            highScores.text = "SCORE: " + score.ToString() + " (the HIGH SCORE is " + currentHighScore.ToString() + ")";
        }
    }
}
```

I would then call the function GameOver() once the end trigger has fired. Good luck!

Comment: I have tried your code(it is way neater than mine haha), and it seems to be working. You see my problem previously was that it was working but sometimes the already calculated the high score will add again with the points. What your code seems different from mine(aside from the neatness) is that instead of using the the unity update function, I am calling a created function. So I am wondering whether the problem was the update() function itself

Comment: As long as PlayerController.count and timeController.sec are stable it should not matter that you were updating the display every frame... so it is a good question. My gut feeling tells me that it might be a rounding error. I should add an f after "/2" like "/2f", or put a (float) in front, and use float while calculating. On a phone, so I have a bit of a problem seeing the whole code - try it :).

Comment: I have not used the float as I wanted the high score to be a whole number. also when I tried it, the PlayerPrefs.SetInt() had an error where it said it could not convert from float to int

Comment: It is completely OK to use int for the high-score, I don't think users would like decimal numbers... But, as soon as you are dividing or using floats, you might experience rounding off "errors" (in one way it is not real errors, it may just "look" strange - especially if we show rounded off values but calculates with decimals), Do the timeController.sec return a float or an int, and is it the same as the timeController.timeText.text string? I will update my answer and add some helpful debug-statements.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the replies, its really helping me haha. As for the rounding off 'errors', yea there are some problems. the timeController.sec returns an int. and it is the same but different format (i.e timeController.sec =  18, timeController.timeText.text  = 0:18), whereas if its above 1 minute (i.e timeController.sec =  18, timeController.timeText.text  = 1:18)